# Price change with auto renewable subscription

Tags: android, ios, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

We are developing an app for both platforms(Android and iOS) with the implementation of in-app purchase. There is a need to retain the previous subscription price for old users for a certain custom defined period of time after the change of subscription price. Is there any way to handle situations like this? We have maintained user purchase history in our local DB.

Answer (score 0):

**Apple(iOS) provides a way to retain the original price for existing users. If you increase price for all the existing and new user, existing user will give their consent for the same to continue the subscription, otherwise, apple will stop the billing for those customers**

[image]